# Retrieving a element with multiple xpaths

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

This isn't much of a coding question but one about what options should I take next. I've just started using selenium about a week ago and started to get the hang of most of its function.

I was working on a work project to login into various websites until I ran into a issue where I was getting this error when I tried to find the password field

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

I went ahead and double checked the name & id  but I couldn't find the field using locators like .id, name, and xpath. I inspected the xpath with Firebug and noticed that it returned two results instead of one.

Current `Xpath` looks like this

```
.//*[@id='password']
```

I was wondering if anyone could point me to the right direct when  dealing with something like this.

Comment: Share html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `id` attribute suppose to be unique value, but there are some cases when front-end developer just hide part of `DOM`, create similar and forget to remove hidden one.

In such case you can (if it possible) ask developer to get rid of redundant code or use index as

```
"(.//*[@id='password'])[2]"
```

Comment: Yeah this pretty much solved my issue. I was able to select the correct xpath.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this you need to use another unique DOM element (parent, ancestor, sibling, child) with connection to the element you are looking for. For example In those html snippets

```
<div id='a'>
  <div id='password'></div>
</div>
```

And

```
<div id='b'>
  <div id='password'></div>
</div>
```

`.//*[@id='password']` will have two results

However

```
.//*[@id='b']/[@id='password']
```

Will have only one result

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your queries one by one:

1. `error when I tried to find the password field` : This is because the property which you have mentioned id/name/css/xpath was incorrect.
2. `ElementNotVisibleException` : I doubt it was for the password_field at all. Reason behind that is, normally login field & password field stays on the same container. Either those resides on the HTML DOM (which gets loaded completely once the page loading is complete) or they may reside within a frame/iFrame (there are other measures to handle them which I am not covering here). But those 2 elements stays on the same container. So if you have found out the login_field element, password_field is just a step away.
3. `inspected the xpath with Firebug and noticed that it returned two results` : That's because the xpath which you are using doesnot identifies an unique element. There can be multiple elements on the HTML DOM with the same `id` attribute set to "password". But definitely the `xpath`of those elements will be different and unique.
4. What you should do?

   I will suggest you the following:

   a. Try to identify each element on a webpage following the attributes in sequence: id, name, visibleText, css, xpath.

   b. Try to identify a unique **logical** xpath for elements using the other properties of the elements defined within the HTML tag. Cross check your xpath through Firebug/Firepath. There are some other handy xpath checker available too. Take help of those.

Let me know if this answers your question.